# Catch 500 code on submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, submit

I have submit function on form

Here is code of function

```
 export function submit(): void {
    $("#sequence").val(Number($("#sequence").val()) + 1);
    $("#search_results").addClass("overlay");
    $("#filter_form").submit();
  }
```

this function called in onUpdated method

Here is code

```
 // This is what triggers when we anything has been changed.
  function onUpdated(): void {
    if (!skipSubmit) {
      submit();
    }
  }
```

I sometimes have 500 code request from back-end and need to show for example alert on it.

I need to catch 500 status from request.

I wonder how I can do this in this code, because I have only $("#filter_form").submit();?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
$('#filter_form').submit(function(event) {

    //serialize the data in the form in JSON
    var formData = $("#filter_form").serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : //your url
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode          : true
    }).done(function(data) {
       //here it comes if there are no error in the server
    }).fail(function(data){
       //when it fails (so error 500)
       //handle your error
    )};
    event.preventDefault();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting your form synchronously. The browser always show the response for synchronous requests. you have 2 option to show user friendly error messages:

**1- The server generates a user friendly html page and returns it to the client** (you should handle the error at the server and generate the error page)

**2- send request asynchronously (Ajax) and catch the error at the client and show a proper message to the user:**

```
$.ajax(“/url-to-post”, {
   data: $("#filter_form").serialize(), // serialize form data
   success: function(){
      //... 
   },

   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
      //...
   },

});
```